# Discord py 'int not callable'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

oh god, here I go with another damage system... So I am really new to discord bot coding but I have everything that goes above and below, it's the command that's bad. It says that the two lines with giant arrows pointing to them are the culprits, also, Aditya Tomar if you are seeing this. Yes, I'm making another one, and no, I don't know why... The command I input is ?fight followed by 15 other numbers.

`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'int' object is not callable` is what the error was specifically btw.

```
###Le epic variables###
WWT = 0
AAS = 0
ASTR = 0
ASPD = 0
DAS = 0
AL = 0
DL = 0
TB = 0
DR = 0
AR = 0
DP = 0
SB = 0
DD = 0
ASK = 0
WC = 0
CC = 0
DoubleAtk = 1
critatk = 1


###Le epic command###
@client.command()
async def fight(ctx, WWT : int, ASTR : int, ASPD : int, DAS : int, AL : int, DL : int, TB : int, DR : int, AR : int, DP : int, SB : int, DD : int, ASK : int, WC : int, CC : int):
    global AAS
    global critatk
    if WWT > ASTR():                    <---------------------- this thing
        AAS = ASPD - (WWT - ASTR)
    else:
        AAS = ASPD
    global DoubleAtk
    if (AAS - DAS) > 4():                 <-------------------- and this thing
        DoubleAtk = 2
    crit_rate = ((WC + ASK) / 2) + SB + CC
    def did_crit():
        random.randint(1, 100)
    DP = TB + DR + SB
    Avoid = AAS + (AL / 2) + TB

    for i in range(DoubleAtk):
        did_crit()
        if did_crit == crit_rate():
            critatk = 3
        damage = (ASTR - DD) * critatk
        await ctx.send(damage)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to call some parameters as if they are functions, your error is basically telling you that you cannot call a parameter, for example in your `if WWT > ASTR():`  or `if (AAS - DAS) > 4():` you are calling the integers as functions, which are not callable.

Your corrected code should look something like this:

```
###Le epic variables###
WWT = 0
AAS = 0
ASTR = 0
ASPD = 0
DAS = 0
AL = 0
DL = 0
TB = 0
DR = 0
AR = 0
DP = 0
SB = 0
DD = 0
ASK = 0
WC = 0
CC = 0
DoubleAtk = 1
critatk = 1


###Le epic command###
@client.command()
async def fight(ctx, WWT : int, ASTR : int, ASPD : int, DAS : int, AL : int, DL : int, TB : int, DR : int, AR : int, DP : int, SB : int, DD : int, ASK : int, WC : int, CC : int):
    global AAS
    global critatk
    if WWT > ASTR:                    
        AAS = ASPD - (WWT - ASTR)
    else:
        AAS = ASPD
    global DoubleAtk
    if (AAS - DAS) > 4:   
        DoubleAtk = 2
    crit_rate = ((WC + ASK) / 2) + SB + CC
    def did_crit():
        random.randint(1, 100)
    DP = TB + DR + SB
    Avoid = AAS + (AL / 2) + TB

    for i in range(DoubleAtk):
        did_crit()
        if did_crit() == crit_rate:
            critatk = 3
        damage = (ASTR - DD) * critatk
        await ctx.send(damage)
```

Notice how `did_crit()` actually needs to be called as a function (because it is), while `crit_rate` does not, as it is an integer.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see, I don't think you need to include the parentheses after `ASTR` and `4` in those if-statements. Try this out:

```py
if WWT > ASTR:                  
        AAS = ASPD - (WWT - ASTR)
    else:
        AAS = ASPD
    global DoubleAtk
    if (AAS - DAS) > 4:       
        DoubleAtk = 2
```